# Function on resize não habilita eventos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um pequeno problema no meu script que não consigo resolver.
Tenho uma função que desabilita o hover e também quero que habilite o hover.
Já consegui desabilitar nas agora não consigo habilitar.

Aqui está o código:

```
function adicionarBotao(){

  $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
  $('.collapseBotao').remove();
  var botao = '<button class="collapseBotao">dasds</button>';

  var numeroDeBotoes = $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').children('.collapseBotao');

  console.log(numeroDeBotoes.length);
  if(numeroDeBotoes.length == 0){
    $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').prepend(botao);
  }
```

}

Comment: Enganei me a colar. já está obrigado

Comment: Quando dou refresh não está returnando 0

Comment: O que tenho que fazer?

Comment: Já resolvi. Quando entro na função apago todos os botões

Comment: Mas agora não dá para clicar nos botões.

Comment: Já refiz obrigadfo

Comment: Vc desabilita os eventos com `.off()`... para habilitar de novo, vc precisa chamar novamente o código que habilita, tipo `$("elemento"). on("mouseenter")... etc...`.

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, já que você desabilita os eventos com:

```
$('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

O que você tem que fazer é chamar novamente o código que habilita os eventos. Para não ter que repetir o mesmo código, coloque-os em uma função e chame-a no carregamento da página e quando você adicionar o botão (se é isso que deseja). Então ficaria assim:

```
$(function(){
   $(window).on("resize", adicionarBotao);
   eventos(); // chama a função

   // função que habilita os eventos
   function eventos(){
      $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').on("mouseenter", function(){
         console.log("entrou");
      }).on("mouseleave", function(){
         console.log("saiu");
      });
   }

   function adicionarBotao(){

     $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
     $('.collapseBotao').remove();
     var botao = '<button class="collapseBotao">dasds</button>';

     var numeroDeBotoes = $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').children('.collapseBotao');

     console.log(numeroDeBotoes.length);
     if(numeroDeBotoes.length == 0){
       $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').prepend(botao);
       eventos(); // chama a função para habilitar os eventos novamente
     }
   }
});
```